# How to Create Thread in Class Extending Fragment

Tags: android

How to Remove Error Which is at `t.start();`

```
public class Timer extends Fragment {

TextView tv1;
Thread t1;
Date d1;
int hour,min,sec;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.timer, container, false);
    //((TextView)android.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("Timer");
    return android;

  //tv1 = (TextView)findviewById(R.id.textView1);

t1 = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            while (!isInterrupted()) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                  d1 = new Date();
                  hour = d1.getHours();
                  min = d1.getMinutes();
                  sec = d1.getSeconds();
                  String displaytime =  hour+":"+min+":"+sec ;
                //  tv1.setText(displaytime);
                ((TextView)android.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(displaytime);
                         }});//runOnUiThread ends here
              }//While ends here
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }//Catch ends here
    }
```

/* ECLIPSE IS SHOWING ERROR IN BELOW `t1.start();` */

```
    t1.start();

    private void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
};//Thread Ends here
}//Oncreate




}   //Fragment
```

Comment: What error does it show??

Answer (score 0):

**You are making the thread after `return` statement.**

Just shift the `return android;` line to after the thread ends.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.timer, container, false);

t1 = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            while (!isInterrupted()) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                  d1 = new Date();
                  hour = d1.getHours();
                  min = d1.getMinutes();
                  sec = d1.getSeconds();
                  String displaytime =  hour+":"+min+":"+sec ;
                //  tv1.setText(displaytime);
                ((TextView)android.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(displaytime);
                         }});//runOnUiThread ends here
              }//While ends here
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }//Catch ends here
    }
/* ECLIPSE IS SHOWING ERROR IN BELOW t1.start(); */

    t1.start();

    private void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
};//Thread Ends here 


return android;
}//Oncreate

} //Fragment
```

Answer (score -1):

Please post the error eclipse showing.
And statement  "return android;" should be the always last line for oncreateview method.